# Virtualbox keeps aborting

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise on my host, and a Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox.  My VM keeps aborting periodically.  This is what I see in my logs:

```
VBox:
00:00:35.201091 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:35.201466 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=8 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll
00:00:35.201558 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:36.319441 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners.
00:00:36.319523 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::adjustGuestScreenSize: Adjust guest-screen size if necessary.
00:00:36.319571 GUI: UIMachineView::sltPerformGuestResize: Sending guest size-hint to screen 0 as 1366x664
00:00:36.319652 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (1366x664x32)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
00:00:36.319669 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:00:36.319679 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:36.320396 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1fff8, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:00:36.772515 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1558, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:00:36.772596 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000d7d0000 w=1366 h=664 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1558 flags=0x1
00:00:36.772718 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=1366x664, Sending to async-handler
00:00:36.772820 GUI: UIMachineView::sltHandleNotifyChange: Screen=0, Size=1366x664
00:00:36.772868 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::handleNotifyChange: Size=1366x664
00:00:36.772902 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=1366x664, Directly using source bitmap content
00:00:36.774031 GUI: UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest-screen size-hint for screen 0 as 1366x664
00:00:36.802471 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1558, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:00:38.530469 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=16 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll
00:00:38.530538 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:46.029712 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x1) seamless: yes, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:00:46.030072 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners.
00:00:46.030145 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::adjustGuestScreenSize: Adjust guest-screen size if necessary.
00:00:46.030161 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:00:46.030170 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:00:46.065413 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x1 -> 0x5) seamless: yes, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: yes
00:00:46.065620 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:00:46.065657 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5

VBoxHardening:
\system32\comctl32.dll' -> 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll' [redir]
1d10.1d24: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll [redoing WinVerifyTrust]
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hFile=0000000000000528 pwszName=\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: Cached context 0000000002617000
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hCatAdmin=0000000002617000
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: cbHash=20 wszDigest=761964761EE466757E306124E042F4C2ACBEA092
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: WinVerifyTrust => 0x0; cat='C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\Package_3_for_KB3059317~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat'; file='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll'
1d10.1d24: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile -> 0 (org 22900)
1d10.1d24: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: 0 (was 22900) fWinVerifyTrust=1 for '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll'
1d10.1d24: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll (Input=C:\WINDOWS\system32\comctl32.dll, rcNtResolve=0x0) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008b0a20:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\WINDOWS\system32 [calling]
1d10.1d24: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fef8c20000 'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18837_none_a4d981ff711297b6\comctl32.dll'
1d10.21b8: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\avrt.dll
1d10.21b8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\system32\avrt.dll (Input=avrt.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008b0a20:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\WINDOWS\system32 [calling]
1d10.21b8: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefb8e0000 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\avrt.dll'
1d10.868: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\mswsock.dll
1d10.868: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008b0a20:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\WINDOWS\system32 [calling]
1d10.868: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefc8f0000 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll'
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hFile=00000000000010a0 pwszName=\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: Cached context 0000000002617000
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: hCatAdmin=0000000002617000
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: cbHash=20 wszDigest=1EFFE58BB9FD8A94FD1609B7F82A43C8E09D98AA
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile: WinVerifyTrust => 0x0; cat='C:\WINDOWS\system32\CatRoot\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}\ntpe.cat'; file='\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL'
1d10.868: supR3HardNtViCallWinVerifyTrustCatFile -> 0 (org 22900)
1d10.868: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheScheduleImports: Import todo: #1 'ws2_32.dll'.
1d10.868: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 0 (\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL) WinVerifyTrust
1d10.868: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL
1d10.868: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'ws2_32.dll'...
1d10.868: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'ws2_32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\ws2_32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
1d10.868: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008b0a20:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\WINDOWS\system32 [calling]
1d10.868: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL
1d10.868: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007fefc300000 LB 0x00007000 C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll [fFlags=0x0]
1d10.868: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\WSHTCPIP.DLL
1d10.868: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefc300000 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll'

VBox.log
00:00:49.764047 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=7 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll
00:00:49.764115 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:49.764342 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=8 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll
00:00:49.764416 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:00:50.057521 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cached rc=VERR_LDRVI_NOT_SIGNED fImage=1 fProtect=0x0 fAccess=0x0 cHits=16 \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll
00:00:50.057600 supR3HardenedErrorV: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: rejecting 'C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll' (C:\Program Files\Tumbleweed\Desktop Validator\tmwdcapiclient.dll): rcNt=0xc0000190
00:01:00.780585 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners.
00:01:00.780676 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::adjustGuestScreenSize: Adjust guest-screen size if necessary.
00:01:00.780705 GUI: UIMachineView::sltPerformGuestResize: Sending guest size-hint to screen 0 as 1366x664
00:01:00.780765 VMMDev: SetVideoModeHint: Got a video mode hint (1366x664x32)@(0x0),(1;0) at 0
00:01:00.780783 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:01:00.780793 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:01:00.781551 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1fff8, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:01:01.923631 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1558, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:01:01.923673 Display::handleDisplayResize: uScreenId=0 pvVRAM=000000000d500000 w=1366 h=664 bpp=32 cbLine=0x1558 flags=0x1
00:01:01.923736 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::NotifyChange: Screen=0, Origin=0x0, Size=1366x664, Sending to async-handler
00:01:01.923832 GUI: UIMachineView::sltHandleNotifyChange: Screen=0, Size=1366x664
00:01:01.923863 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::handleNotifyChange: Size=1366x664
00:01:01.923890 GUI: UIFrameBufferPrivate::performResize: Size=1366x664, Directly using source bitmap content
00:01:01.924494 GUI: UIMachineView::storeGuestSizeHint: Storing guest-screen size-hint for screen 0 as 1366x664
00:01:02.000896 VBVA: InfoScreen: [0] @0,0 1366x664, line 0x1558, BPP 32, flags 0x1
00:05:06.910646 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x0 -> 0x1) seamless: yes, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: no
00:05:06.910889 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state really changed, notifying listeners.
00:05:06.910970 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::adjustGuestScreenSize: Adjust guest-screen size if necessary.
00:05:06.910988 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:05:06.910998 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:05:06.927448 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x1 -> 0x5) seamless: yes, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: yes
00:05:06.927673 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:05:06.927716 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:05:08.722899 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:05:36.899265 VMMDev: Guest Additions capability report: (0x5 -> 0x5) seamless: yes, hostWindowMapping: no, graphics: yes
00:05:36.899523 GUI: UISession::sltAdditionsChange: GA state change event came, notifying listeners.
00:05:36.899565 GUI: UIMachineLogicNormal::sltCheckForRequestedVisualStateType: Requested-state=0, Machine-state=5
00:09:16.447257 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:34.175826 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:38.881833 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:40.807901 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:43.479927 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:45.734323 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:46.277558 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
00:09:48.619904 OHCI#0: Lagging too far behind, not trying to catch up anymore. Expect glitches with USB devices
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (or a similar) problem, running 14.04.3 LTS.

Currently, the repos are sending out VirtualBox 4.3.34 and Extension Pack 4.3.10. After some research, I learned that these are not likely to be compatible, and frankly I'm surprised that the "stable" repo is in this state.

I went to the VirtualBox site, and found this page: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

See where it says "If you are using VirtualBox 4.3.34..." and there's a download link? Give that a shot. I downloaded it and when I clicked on it, it opened automatically in VBox. Now Windows is booting again!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be because of the virtual box problem. it might because of the memory issue. If you have less swap and it gets full then there is high chance of vbox machine gets aborted.
To check that first check weather your swap memory is full or not using htop command. If htop is not installed (`sudo apt install htop` in ubuntu, check for other flavors)
Put `htop` command and see if the swap is getting full. If yes you can increase the swap memory by following command

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

And then you do `htop` and see the swap size. it should be 8gb and not full. now your vbox won't be aborting repeatedly.
It solved my vbox problem after lot of research